# Unity Game Crash occurring 10 to 20 seconds after game load

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, crash, crash-reports

I have recently released an early access game using Unity HDRP.

Unlike the demo version, I have received reports from a few users about experiencing crashes approximately 10-20 seconds after loading every map.

The early access version has a significantly larger volume, but this specific crash appears to be rare and remains unresolved.

I have included the lines of the log file that are specifically related to the crash.

(The parts regarding 'Unable to add the requested character to font asset [PretendardJP-Light SDF]'s atlas texture.' have been resolved and do not appear to be related to the crash. Please ignore these parts!)

---

Would it be also possible to decipher the following phrase specifically:

" (Address: 00007FFC61461DE4) 0x00007FFC61461DE4 (UnityPlayer) (function-name not available) ERROR: SymGetSymFromAddr64, GetLastError: '试图访问无效的地址。"?

I believe this part provides specific information about the issues.

("试图访问无效的地址" says "Attempting to access an invalid address.")

Wishing everyone a wonderful start to the week!

+) Unity version is 2019.4.40 LTS

---

+) I have identified a few stack errors that I believed could be potential causes and addressed them, but the crash still persists.

There are two other areas that appear suspicious: the custom Physics Fixed Update method and GPU Instancing, which were not present in the demo. I will attempt to revert these changes and provide an update with the results.

+) I've also attached the requested log for the crash itself!

Unfortunately, I had to cut out some chunks due to the character limit of the body (which doesn't allow more than 30,000 characters).

However, as you might see, it appears to be a repeated failure of certain components.

---

The link is for the full detail of the crash log.

https://1drv.ms/f/s!Am3CDBrDVq2PnGcda_zkPX0UW1j4?e=FXM0LA

Thank you again for everyone who looks into the issue.

---

```
---

Crash!!!
SymInit: Symbol-SearchPath: '.;E:\steam\steamapps\common\The Highrise Test;E:\steam\steamapps\common\The Highrise Test;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\system32;SRV*C:\websymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;', symOptions: 534, UserName: 'Kud'
OS-Version: 10.0.0
E:\steam\steamapps\common\The Highrise Test\The Highrise Test.exe:The Highrise Test.exe (00007FF695300000), size: 667648 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 2019.4.40.50731
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll:ntdll.dll (00007FFD2BF30000), size: 2183168 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL:KERNEL32.DLL (00007FFD2B5E0000), size: 802816 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll:KERNELBASE.dll (00007FFD29300000), size: 3817472 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
E:\steam\steamapps\common\The Highrise Test\UnityPlayer.dll:UnityPlayer.dll (00007FFC61010000), size: 27111424 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 2019.4.40.50731
C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll:USER32.dll (00007FFD2A470000), size: 1748992 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll:win32u.dll (00007FFD296B0000), size: 155648 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll:GDI32.dll (00007FFD2A6E0000), size: 167936 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll:gdi32full.dll (00007FFD29AD0000), size: 1146880 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll:msvcp_win.dll (00007FFD296E0000), size: 630784 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll:ucrtbase.dll (00007FFD29780000), size: 1118208 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll:eek:le32.dll (00007FFD2B340000), size: 1687552 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll:combase.dll (00007FFD29DC0000), size: 3710976 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll:RPCRT4.dll (00007FFD2AAE0000), size: 1142784 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHLWAPI.dll:SHLWAPI.dll (00007FFD2AA20000), size: 385024 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll:msvcrt.dll (00007FFD2A150000), size: 684032 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 7.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll:VERSION.dll (00007FFD219B0000), size: 40960 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\SETUPAPI.dll:SETUPAPI.dll (00007FFD2ACD0000), size: 4669440 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll:ADVAPI32.dll (00007FFD2AC00000), size: 712704 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll:sechost.dll (00007FFD2A3C0000), size: 671744 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll:SHELL32.dll (00007FFD2B6B0000), size: 8536064 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll:OLEAUT32.dll (00007FFD29CE0000), size: 880640 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.dll:IMM32.dll (00007FFD2A620000), size: 200704 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPT32.dll:CRYPT32.dll (00007FFD298A0000), size: 1470464 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll:WS2_32.dll (00007FFD2A660000), size: 462848 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll:WINMM.dll (00007FFD1E7B0000), size: 212992 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\OPENGL32.dll:OPENGL32.dll (00007FFC668B0000), size: 1048576 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll:bcrypt.dll (00007FFD28C00000), size: 163840 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\HID.DLL:HID.DLL (00007FFD27370000), size: 57344 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINHTTP.dll:WINHTTP.dll (00007FFD215B0000), size: 1273856 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\GLU32.dll:GLU32.dll (00007FFD24A40000), size: 184320 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dxcore.dll:dxcore.dll (00007FFD25BB0000), size: 221184 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
E:\steam\gameoverlayrenderer64.dll:gameoverlayrenderer64.dll (00007FFC65AF0000), size: 1613824 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 8.9.90.16
C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL:pSAPI.DLL (00007FFD2BEE0000), size: 32768 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\kernel.appcore.dll:kernel.appcore.dll (00007FFD27C80000), size: 98304 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll:bcryptPrimitives.dll (00007FFD29BF0000), size: 503808 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll:uxtheme.dll (00007FFD258B0000), size: 700416 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll:shcore.dll (00007FFD2B240000), size: 995328 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\windows.storage.dll:windows.storage.dll (00007FFD26620000), size: 9363456 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wintypes.dll:wintypes.dll (00007FFD264E0000), size: 1302528 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll:profapi.dll (00007FFD29230000), size: 135168 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
E:\steam\steamapps\common\The Highrise Test\MonoBleedingEdge\EmbedRuntime\mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll:mono-2.0-bdwgc.dll (00007FFC65380000), size: 7790592 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: ''
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\iphlpapi.dll:iphlpapi.dll (00007FFD277F0000), size: 184320 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\MSCTF.dll:MSCTF.dll (0000020BAE670000), size: 1273856 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\d3d11.dll:d3d11.dll (00007FFD24290000), size: 2453504 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dxgi.dll:dxgi.dll (00007FFD25A20000), size: 1015808 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\directxdatabasehelper.dll:directxdatabasehelper.dll (00007FFD21EC0000), size: 303104 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispsig.inf_amd64_777742171a918a50\nvldumdx.dll:nvldumdx.dll (00007FFD1EDD0000), size: 770048 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 31.0.15.3598
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\msasn1.dll:msasn1.dll (00007FFD282D0000), size: 73728 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cryptnet.dll:cryptnet.dll (00007FFD25C20000), size: 204800 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\drvstore.dll:drvstore.dll (00007FFD274F0000), size: 1445888 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\devobj.dll:devobj.dll (00007FFD28FE0000), size: 180224 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CFGMGR32.dll:CFGMGR32.dll (00007FFD29010000), size: 319488 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wldp.dll:wldp.dll (00007FFD28490000), size: 294912 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\cryptbase.dll:cryptbase.dll (00007FFD28480000), size: 49152 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\wintrust.dll:wintrust.dll (00007FFD29C70000), size: 438272 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\imagehlp.dll:imagehlp.dll (00007FFD2B560000), size: 126976 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\CRYPTSP.dll:CRYPTSP.dll (00007FFD28FA0000), size: 110592 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll:rsaenh.dll (00007FFD27CA0000), size: 217088 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispsig.inf_amd64_777742171a918a50\nvwgf2umx.dll:nvwgf2umx.dll (00007FFD12A30000), size: 99463168 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 31.0.15.3598
C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispsig.inf_amd64_777742171a918a50\Display.NvContainer\MessageBus.dll:MessageBus.dll (00007FFD12200000), size: 7565312 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 1.22.2758.1620
C:\WINDOWS\System32\clbcatq.dll:clbcatq.dll (00007FFD2A830000), size: 720896 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 2001.12.10941.16384
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemprox.dll:wbemprox.dll (00007FFD20650000), size: 65536 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\wbemcomn.dll:wbemcomn.dll (00007FFD1DB10000), size: 524288 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\wbemsvc.dll:wbemsvc.dll (00007FFD1D230000), size: 81920 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wbem\fastprox.dll:fastprox.dll (00007FFD1D2A0000), size: 1015808 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\amsi.dll:amsi.dll (00007FFD0F740000), size: 118784 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\NSI.dll:NSI.dll (00007FFD2A720000), size: 36864 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc.DLL:dhcpcsvc.DLL (00007FFD219F0000), size: 126976 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\MMDevApi.dll:MMDevApi.dll (00007FFD1E4F0000), size: 643072 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\AUDIOSES.DLL:AUDIOSES.DLL (00007FFD0D260000), size: 1986560 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\resourcepolicyclient.dll:resourcepolicyclient.dll (00007FFD25DB0000), size: 86016 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\powrprof.dll:powrprof.dll (00007FFD28C30000), size: 315392 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\UMPDC.dll:UMPDC.dll (00007FFD28810000), size: 77824 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\xinput1_3.dll:xinput1_3.dll (0000000000400000), size: 122880 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 9.18.944.0
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dcomp.dll:dcomp.dll (00007FFD24510000), size: 2387968 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll:dwmapi.dll (00007FFD25B40000), size: 176128 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\ProgramData\FPSMonitor\hooks\fps-mon64.dll:fps-mon64.dll (00007FFD01760000), size: 634880 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 6.0.0.5447
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\textinputframework.dll:textinputframework.dll (00007FFD0FB50000), size: 1339392 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\Windows\System32\Windows.UI.dll:Windows.UI.dll (00007FFD0D0B0000), size: 1523712 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
E:\steam\steamapps\common\The Highrise Test\The Highrise Test_Data\Plugins\x86_64\steam_api64.dll:steam_api64.dll (00007FFCA6920000), size: 311296 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 6.91.21.57
E:\steam\steamclient64.dll:steamclient64.dll (00007FFC76010000), size: 22986752 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 8.9.90.16
E:\steam\vstdlib_s64.dll:vstdlib_s64.dll (00007FFC75DB0000), size: 733184 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 8.9.90.16
E:\steam\tier0_s64.dll:tier0_s64.dll (00007FFC75E70000), size: 1667072 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 8.9.90.16
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\Secur32.dll:Secur32.dll (00007FFD0F4F0000), size: 49152 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSWSOCK.dll:MSWSOCK.dll (00007FFD28350000), size: 430080 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SSPICLI.DLL:SSPICLI.DLL (00007FFD27F20000), size: 270336 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL:dhcpcsvc6.DLL (00007FFD21A10000), size: 102400 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll:DNSAPI.dll (00007FFD27860000), size: 995328 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll:rasadhlp.dll (00007FFD219E0000), size: 40960 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\fwpuclnt.dll:fwpuclnt.dll (00007FFD20730000), size: 540672 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\gpapi.dll:gpapi.dll (00007FFD283E0000), size: 155648 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\system32\napinsp.dll:napinsp.dll (00007FFC77740000), size: 94208 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\system32\pnrpnsp.dll:pnrpnsp.dll (00007FFC77720000), size: 110592 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll:winrnr.dll (00007FFC77760000), size: 69632 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\system32\wshbth.dll:wshbth.dll (00007FFD21EA0000), size: 86016 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\system32\nlansp_c.dll:nlansp_c.dll (00007FFD0CFC0000), size: 135168 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dbghelp.dll:dbghelp.dll (00007FFD28C80000), size: 2285568 (result: 0), SymType: '-deferred-', PDB: '', fileVersion: 10.0.23471.1000
========== OUTPUTTING STACK TRACE ==================
ERROR: SymGetSymFromAddr64, GetLastError: '试图访问无效的地址。
' (Address: 00007FFC61461DE4)
0x00007FFC61461DE4 (UnityPlayer) (function-name not available)
ERROR: SymGetSymFromAddr64, GetLastError: '试图访问无效的地址。
' (Address: 00007FFC6146640E)
0x00007FFC6146640E (UnityPlayer) (function-name not available)
ERROR: SymGetSymFromAddr64, GetLastError: '试图访问无效的地址。
' (Address: 00007FFC615225F0)
0x00007FFC615225F0 (UnityPlayer) (function-name not available)
ERROR: SymGetSymFromAddr64, GetLastError: '试图访问无效的地址。
' (Address: 00007FFC61522D4B)
0x00007FFC61522D4B (UnityPlayer) (function-name not available)
ERROR: SymGetSymFromAddr64, GetLastError: '试图访问无效的地址。
' (Address: 00007FFC6152422D)
0x00007FFC6152422D (UnityPlayer) (function-name not available)
ERROR: SymGetSymFromAddr64, GetLastError: '试图访问无效的地址。
' (Address: 00007FFC61524308)
0x00007FFC61524308 (UnityPlayer) (function-name not available)
0x00007FFC61855E28 (UnityPlayer) UnityMain
0x00007FFD2B5F26AD (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk
0x00007FFD2BF8AA08 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart
========== END OF STACKTRACE ===========
A crash has been intercepted by the crash handler. For call stack and other details, see the latest crash report generated in:
* C:/Users/Kud/AppData/Local/Temp/Studio Hatch.Co.Ltd/The Highrise Test/Crashes


---
```

**CRASH LOGS**

```
    06/04/2023 05:11:07.720: DebugHelper Symbol Search Path......: ;E:\Special K
06/04/2023 05:11:07.720: Unable to load Special K Debug Symbols ('E:\Special K\SpecialK64.pdb'), crash log will not be accurate.

==================================================================================================
 <+> System Memory Load....: 31%
  # Current Working Set....:  1.530 GiB  (Max Used:  1.530 GiB out of Total Physical: 31.772 GiB)
  # Current Virtual Memory.:  9.730 GiB  (Max Used:  9.773 GiB)

 <+> GPU0 Load.............: 78.00% at 64.00°C
  - D3D11 Textures Cached..: 717 ( 1.762 GiB Used, Quota:  2.000 GiB); 0 Evictions / 7 Hits
  - Current VRAM In Use....:  4.737 GiB / Max Useable VRAM: 23.988 GiB
==================================================================================================

06/04/2023 05:11:59.013:    Unhandled Top-Level Exception (c0000005):

06/04/2023 05:11:59.013:    Unhandled Top-Level Exception (c0000005):

06/04/2023 05:11:59.013:    Unhandled Top-Level Exception (c0000005):

06/04/2023 05:11:59.013:    Unhandled Top-Level Exception (c0000005):

06/04/2023 05:11:59.013:    Unhandled Top-Level Exception (c0000005):

-----------------------------------------------------------
[! Except !]    << EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION >>
-----------------------------------------------------------
[  Thread  ]  ~ Name.....: "Job.Worker 5"
[ FaultMod ]  # File.....: 'E:\steam\steamapps\common\The Highrise\UnityPlayer.dll'
[ FaultMod ]  * RIP Addr.: UnityPlayer.dll+000000000074F7A7h
[StackFrame] <-> Rip=7ff8fd7df7a7h, Rsp=0036c67ff460h, Rbp=0036c67ff560h
[StackFrame] >-< Rsi=000000000064h, Rdi=000000000000h
[  GP Reg  ]   rax:    0x000000000000    rbx:    0x000000000019
[  GP Reg  ]   rcx:    0x000000000bb8    rdx:    0x000080008000
[  GP Reg  ]   r8:     0x020c8000bf70    r9:     0x0000c67ff500
[  GP Reg  ]   r10:    0x0036c67ff5e0    r11:    0x020cc02e3c10
[  GP Reg  ]   r12:    0x000000001565    r13:    0x020c800361f0
[  GP Reg  ]   r14:    0x000000000000    r15:    0x000000000000
[ GP Flags ]   EFlags: 0x00010246
-----------------------------------------------------------
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
    KERNEL32.DLL >  BaseThreadInitThunk
       ntdll.dll >   RtlUserThreadStart
-----------------------------------------------------------

06/04/2023 05:11:59.013:    Unhandled Top-Level Exception (c0000005):

-----------------------------------------------------------
[! Except !]    << EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION >>
-----------------------------------------------------------
[  Thread  ]  ~ Name.....: "Job.Worker 24"
[ FaultMod ]  # File.....: 'E:\steam\steamapps\common\The Highrise\UnityPlayer.dll'
[ FaultMod ]  * RIP Addr.: UnityPlayer.dll+0000000000748CD7h
[StackFrame] <-> Rip=7ff8fd7d8cd7h, Rsp=0036c7afec10h, Rbp=0036c7afed10h
[StackFrame] >-< Rsi=020da017e960h, Rdi=020d2afe35e0h
[  GP Reg  ]   rax:    0x000000000064    rbx:    0x0000003f003f
[  GP Reg  ]   rcx:    0x020c801572d8    rdx:    0x020ce1200500
[  GP Reg  ]   r8:     0x000000000001    r9:     0x000000000000
[  GP Reg  ]   r10:    0x020cc0227a10    r11:    0x020c802d19c8
[  GP Reg  ]   r12:    0x020c80156948    r13:    0x0036c7aff7e0
[  GP Reg  ]   r14:    0x00020000002b    r15:    0x020c8000bf70
[ GP Flags ]   EFlags: 0x00010293
-----------------------------------------------------------
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
    KERNEL32.DLL >  BaseThreadInitThunk
       ntdll.dll >   RtlUserThreadStart
-----------------------------------------------------------

-----------------------------------------------------------
[! Except !]    << EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION >>
-----------------------------------------------------------
[  Thread  ]  ~ Name.....: "Job.Worker 21"
[ FaultMod ]  # File.....: 'E:\steam\steamapps\common\The Highrise\UnityPlayer.dll'
[ FaultMod ]  * RIP Addr.: UnityPlayer.dll+000000000074F7A7h
[StackFrame] <-> Rip=7ff8fd7df7a7h, Rsp=0036c77ff560h, Rbp=0036c77ff660h
[StackFrame] >-< Rsi=000000000064h, Rdi=000000000000h
[  GP Reg  ]   rax:    0x000000000000    rbx:    0x000000000019
[  GP Reg  ]   rcx:    0x000000000bb8    rdx:    0x000080008000
[  GP Reg  ]   r8:     0x020c8000bf70    r9:     0x0000c77ff600
[  GP Reg  ]   r10:    0x0036c77ff6e4    r11:    0x020cc02e3c10
[  GP Reg  ]   r12:    0x000000001565    r13:    0x020c8002fd70
[  GP Reg  ]   r14:    0x000000000000    r15:    0x000000000000
[ GP Flags ]   EFlags: 0x00010246
-----------------------------------------------------------
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
    KERNEL32.DLL >  BaseThreadInitThunk
       ntdll.dll >   RtlUserThreadStart
-----------------------------------------------------------

06/04/2023 05:11:59.014:    Unhandled Top-Level Exception (c0000005):

-----------------------------------------------------------
[! Except !]    << EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION >>
-----------------------------------------------------------
[  Thread  ]  ~ Name.....: "Job.Worker 19"
[ FaultMod ]  # File.....: 'E:\steam\steamapps\common\The Highrise\UnityPlayer.dll'
[ FaultMod ]  * RIP Addr.: UnityPlayer.dll+000000000074F7A7h
[StackFrame] <-> Rip=7ff8fd7df7a7h, Rsp=0036c75ff990h, Rbp=0036c75ffa90h
[StackFrame] >-< Rsi=000000000064h, Rdi=000000000000h
[  GP Reg  ]   rax:    0x000000000000    rbx:    0x000000000019
[  GP Reg  ]   rcx:    0x000000000bb8    rdx:    0x000080008000
[  GP Reg  ]   r8:     0x020c8000bf70    r9:     0x0000c75ffb00
[  GP Reg  ]   r10:    0x0036c75ffb14    r11:    0x020cc02e3c10
[  GP Reg  ]   r12:    0x000000001565    r13:    0x020c80048f50
[  GP Reg  ]   r14:    0x000000000000    r15:    0x000000000000
[ GP Flags ]   EFlags: 0x00010246
-----------------------------------------------------------
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
    KERNEL32.DLL >  BaseThreadInitThunk
       ntdll.dll >   RtlUserThreadStart
-----------------------------------------------------------

06/04/2023 05:11:59.014:    Unhandled Top-Level Exception (c0000005):

06/04/2023 05:11:59.014:    Unhandled Top-Level Exception (c0000005):

-----------------------------------------------------------
[! Except !]    << EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION >>
-----------------------------------------------------------
[  Thread  ]  ~ Name.....: "Job.Worker 16"
[ FaultMod ]  # File.....: 'E:\steam\steamapps\common\The Highrise\UnityPlayer.dll'
[ FaultMod ]  * RIP Addr.: UnityPlayer.dll+000000000074F7A7h
[StackFrame] <-> Rip=7ff8fd7df7a7h, Rsp=0036c72ff8c0h, Rbp=0036c72ff9c0h
[StackFrame] >-< Rsi=000000000064h, Rdi=000000000000h
[  GP Reg  ]   rax:    0x000000000000    rbx:    0x000000000019
[  GP Reg  ]   rcx:    0x000000000bb8    rdx:    0x000080008000
[  GP Reg  ]   r8:     0x020c8000bf70    r9:     0x000000000000
[  GP Reg  ]   r10:    0x0036c72ffa40    r11:    0x020cc02e3c10
[  GP Reg  ]   r12:    0x000000001565    r13:    0x020c80042ad0
[  GP Reg  ]   r14:    0x000000000000    r15:    0x000000000000
[ GP Flags ]   EFlags: 0x00010246
-----------------------------------------------------------
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
 UnityPlayer.dll >            UnityMain
    KERNEL32.DLL >  BaseThreadInitThunk
       ntdll.dll >   RtlUserThreadStart
-----------------------------------------------------------

06/04/2023 05:11:59.015:    Unhandled Top-Level Exception (c0000005):
```

Comment: What about any errors in your Unity Editor? Do you get any similar error when you run the game directly from Unity?

Comment: No errors could be found in the Editor. Only a specific few users are experiencing this problem. Thank you for asking!

Comment: at the end it says more call stack and other details are stored in the Crashes folder, can you post those detailes as well ?

Comment: Yes! I'll post the detail by edit.

Comment: The game's name is "The Highrise" and here is the link for the full detail of the crash log if anyone is interested(The log above is cut due to character limit): https://1drv.ms/f/s!Am3CDBrDVq2PnGcda_zkPX0UW1j4?e=FXM0LA

Comment: It is complicated that some of the error log is not english. Eg the "试图访问无效的地址" portion. What does this say?

Comment: It says 'Attempting to access an invalid address.'

The user is from China. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: We have not received any further test feedback on this matter so far :( Once we do, we will update it accordingly.